# Testing packages against old Mathematica versions

Tags: packages, testing-and-verification

I've made a Mathematica package available, and it's been reported to me that it doesn't work with Mathematica 4.  I've guessed at some of the issues, and provided work arounds, but that process is awkward without being able to try things myself.

I've had licences for various Mathematica versions since I started using it (8, 9, 10, 11).  I was wondering if:

- Do such licences give me access to older versions too (although I expect they may require old os versions to install)?
- Perhaps Wolfram has made really old versions of Mathematica freely available for test purposes, knowing that nobody was likely to want to install them for production use?

Comment: Usually, and for precisely this reason, the best solution is not to support very old versions of Mathematica, and to only support the ones you have access to.

Comment: Mathematica 4 was released in 1999, almost 20 years ago. Trying to make your package compatible is in my opinion a huge waste of time that will involve lots of compromises, and will impact performance in later versions. If it's compatible with 8, you have basically all users covered.   I *know* that the results from [this survey](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2352/12) are biased, but they may still be of some use. Also, be careful: if it's compatible with an older version, it doesn't mean that it works properly with all newer ones.